# use scroll not working || unable to do animation of timeline

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion

[i am trying to make animation of timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBha0.png)
 [but i am stuck here , whenever i add that <motion.div style={....} part line also disappears and motion does not occour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWCZ.png)

[my out put became like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNMOS.png)

i am using useScroll for this animation
everything alright but whenever i add this
line style={{scaleY:scrollYProgress}} the black line disappear and no motion happens

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.